# Firefox is constantly crashing. can't run it anymore

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Firefox crashes immediately after run. Upgrade didn't help. Safe mode didn't help. Refreshing didn't help.

How to dig?

Comment: Dig? With a spade? Remove the profile.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade didn't help? Does that mean you completely uninstalled and reinstalled it?

Comment: likely he wasn't using the latest version of firefox and he pressed the "update firefox" button from within the browser

Comment: What version of Firefox?  I ran into a similar problem with V46 that turned out to be incompatibility with a theme.  If nobody here is able to help, another good source is Mozilla's support forum.  The one for Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-community-support

Comment: Can you enter *about:crashes* in the URL bar and get that page before it crashes? Any dialog box displayed when it crashes?

Comment: It's possible your problem is version specific.  Please post the version number.  Also, try downloading the previous version (or the last one that worked), from Mozilla, and replace the current version with that to see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and download the updated stable release. 
Install it and you go..

You can backup your user profile folder for saving your bookmarks and saved password.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
unfortunately the Mozilla firefox doesn't have any effective crash handler, some things you can do:
1- clean your PC (with something like [Ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)) 
2- change your user in windows and sync firefox data again
3- remove the firefox completely and reinstall it with the official link placed in mozilla website ([this one](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/?scene=2))